# Scrolling text from left to right on a MBED using a LCD display

Tags: c, embedded, mbed

I recently purchased an MBED along with an LCD display. Within the MBED cookbook, I found a piece of code to scroll text from right to left:

```
const char *message = "                  ******Welcome******";

int main() {

while (1) {
int i;
for (i = 0; message[i]; i++) {
    lcd.locate(0,0);
    int j, k = i;
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        if (message[k+j]) {
            lcd.putc(message[k+j]);
        } else {
            lcd.putc(' ');
            k--;
        }
    }
    wait_ms(450);
}    
}
}
```

Could anyone help me figure out how to scroll this text from left to right? Therefore the first letter which would be displayed would be the letter 'e'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `for (i = 0; message[i]; i++)` to `for (i = strlen(message); i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: There are commands `0x18` to shift entire text to left and `0x1C` to shift entire text to right!